# Using cassandra in a data grid to sort and filter data

Tags: sorting, datagrid, cassandra

We are converting from SQL Server to Cassandra for various reasons. The back end system is converted and working and now we are focusing on the front end systems.

In the current system we have a number of Telerik data grids where the app loads all the data and search/sort/filter is done in the grid itself. We want to avoid this and are going to push the search/sort/filter to the DB. In SQL Server this is not a problem because of ad-hoc queries. However in Cassandra it becomes very confusing.

If any operation was allowed then of course a Cassandra table would have to model the data that way. However I was wondering how this is performed in real world scenarios for large amounts of data and large amounts of columns.

For instance, if I had a grid with columns 1, 2, 3, 4 what is the best course of action?

- Highly control what the user can do
- Create a lot of tables to model the data and pick the one to select from
- Don't allow the user to do any data operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As any NoSQL system, Cassandra performs the queries on Primary Keys best. You can of course use secondary indices, but it will be a lot slower.

So the recommended way is to create Materialized Views for all possible queries.

Another way is to use something like Apache Ignite on top of Cassandra to do analytics, but you don't want to use grids for some reason as i get it.